# Serverpilot/digitalocean - you don't have permission to access /index.html on this server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server

I'm testing a digitalocean server with [serverpilot](http://www.serverpilot.io)

It works for half of my sites, but for the other sites (they call that an "app" in serverpilot and digital ocean) I'm getting this error message when trying to reach the pages:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.

Possible causes of this error include:

The request was forbidden by rules in the .htaccess file.
The directory you requested does not have an index.html or index.php file.
The permissions on the file or directory are incorrect.
For details about why the request was forbidden, see the Apache error log at:

/srv/users/SYSUSER/log/APPNAME/APPNAME_apache.error.log
```

Seems to be a permission issue, but something that I don’t understand is why when I upload some websites from my computer in an app directory (via filezilla), the permissions are set by default to 644, and for some other websites they are set to 600?

At what time the permissions are set? Do I need to modify something at apache level? I never had that type of issues on standard hosting platforms where I didn’t have control on servers so I guess this was controlled in the background by the hosting provider? Should I force the permissions somewhere? How?

Many thanks for your help,

Comment: did you ever find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try ensuring the file permissions are 644 on the local files, before copying.

Filezilla incorporates RFC 3659 (facts for files) which the Serverpilot upload server probably supports, so it can replicate the local file permissions when uploading using ftp.

Also File permissions should be visible in the directory listing currently with FileZilla, and should support also chmod for target server via a context menu.